# Overflow issue with airplane animation

Tags: css, animation, overflow, css-animations

I am running an airplane CSS animation on my website turbotobias.dk - I am having a issue with overflow when using the CSS animation. I have tried with overflow-x: hidden and also adjust the left to left px but having a hard time fitting.

How can I solve this CSS issue? Could I make the right to left animation smarter or is there any other overflow: hidden; solutions I could/should use?

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#animate {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 100vw;
  background-image: url(https://www.turbotobias.dk/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Fly-med-banner-TurboTobias-Graphics2.svg);
  width: 663px;
  height: 168px;
  animation: slideLeft 20s linear 0.1s infinite;
}

@keyframes slideLeft {
  from {
    left: 100vw;
  }
  to {
    left: -700px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="animate"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider background animation to avoid the overflow issue. It will also be easier to adjust the position and size of the image:

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url(https://www.turbotobias.dk/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Fly-med-banner-TurboTobias-Graphics2.svg);
  background-size:400px auto;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  animation:slideLeft 5s linear infinite;
}


@keyframes slideLeft {
  from {
    background-position:right -400px top 50%;
  }
  to {
    background-position:left -400px top 50%;
  }
}
```

But for better performance you can use a pseudo element and consider translation like below:

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
body:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-image: url(https://www.turbotobias.dk/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Fly-med-banner-TurboTobias-Graphics2.svg);
  background-position:center;
  background-size:400px auto;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  animation:slideLeft 5s linear infinite;
  
}


@keyframes slideLeft {
  from {
    transform:translateX(100%);
  }
  to {
    transform:translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```